# iPhone 4 Gyroscope/GPS versus Accelerometer/GPS/Compass

Tags: iphone, gps, accelerometer, iphone-4, gyroscope

I am about to use iPhone 4's gyroscope/GPS on a game, to detect rotation and translation. As far as I know, the gyroscope can be used to detect rotations in all 3 axis.

But rotations, at least on the horizontal plane can be detected with the compass, tilts can be detected with the accelerometer and positions with the GPS.

Can a combination of compass/accelerometer/GPS create the same level of detection of gyroscope/GPS?  (I am thinking of allowing this combination for people without iPhone 4).

Will this work perfectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of the gyroscope and accelerometer sensors is much greater than the precision of the compass and GPS.  The compass and GPS are for finding out where the device is on the globe, and the gyroscope and accelerometer are good for finding out where the device has moved in the last few milliseconds.

Therefore it depends upon what you're trying to control with the device's movement.  Trying to simulate a gyroscope input to control a 3D simulation (like the Jenga game Jobs showed in the keynote that introduced the iPhone 4) will not work perfectly with just the compass/accelerometer/GPS.  Figuring out if the device is pointed at the grocery store on the west side of the street instead of the furniture store on the east side of the street in an augmented reality game will work perfectly with just the compass/accelerometer/GPS.

Comment: but how do I detect translation? I will have to use the GPS. The question is: how precise is the GPS? What is the minimum translation it will detect? 10 meters?

Comment: GPS precision depends upon the reception of the radio signals from the GPS satellites at any particular location.  In most areas the precision will be on the order of 10 meters.  Among tall buildings the reception of GPS signals may be blocked, and GPS precision will be even worse.  If your game was using accelerometer tracking to maintain the positioning model, the GPS and compass would be most useful for occasional reorientation updates, just to keep the accelerometer tracking rooted in reality.

Comment: Here is a good example of combining the compass with the gyroscope: http://www.sundh.com/blog/2011/09/stabalize-compass-of-iphone-with-gyroscope/